# how to find maximum value in column multiple times

Tags: excel, max

Is there any way in excel to find max value from a column at regular intervals? I mean say in column "A", I need to find `MAX(A1:A100)`, `MAX(A101:200)`, `MAX(A201:300)`, and so on. It will be in same intervals but have a huge amount of data. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will cycle every 100 rows for every row it is copied or dragged down:

```
=MAX(INDEX(A:A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*100+1):INDEX(A:A,(ROW(1:1)*100)))
```

Unlike OFFSET, INDEX is not volatile.  A volatile function will recalculate every time that Excel recalculates regardless if the underlying data changes or not. If there are a lot of formulas that use OFFSET or INDIRECT it will make a noticeable effect on the recalculation times.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. I am still understanding that. In case I want to change that code to say I want to get the first max value for the first 150 rows in column A, and then find the max values for the next 300 rows and so on. What changes would need to be made?

Comment: Just change both `100`s to the step you want to make.

Comment: One more follow up question: 
Suppose I need to find the max in the 300 rows for 11 times and then the max in next 220 rows, and then continue this pattern (11 times find max in 300 rows and on time in 220 rows), is there an easy way?

Comment: No easy way, it will take some other formula.

Comment: Would you be able to help me get the formula? Will a 'IF' or 'WHILE' should be used?

Comment: This is a new question, and deserves a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=MAX(OFFSET($A$1:$A$100,100*(ROW(A1)-1),0))
```

Note @ScottCraner's point. Liberal use of `OFFSET` can slow your file down.